# ElasticSearch returning all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is the query I am sending to ElasticSearch:

```
http://localhost:9200/user-index/user/_search/?queryb%5Bname%5D=Richard
```

The returned JSON is this:

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "user-index",
      "_type": "user",
      "_id": "WgrvE-DzQJminNreBIsRNA",
      "_score": 1.0,
      "_source": {
        "name": "Richard",
        "db_id": "7"
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "user-index",
      "_type": "user",
      "_id": "GwMOuYbUR8y48RrG4HgXdg",
      "_score": 1.0,
      "_source": {
        "name": "John",
        "db_id": "8"
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "user-index",
      "_type": "user",
      "_id": "C-bgK3pNTNiX9Cz0x8EftA",
      "_score": 1.0,
      "_source": {
        "name": "Harold",
        "db_id": "2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Only one of those actually matches. Why is it sending them all back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch returns all records with the type user in the index user-index because it cannot find the search query. The search query should be specified as a query string in [the parameter "q"](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/uri-request.html) or as [a request body](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/request-body.html).

Try `http://localhost:9200/user-index/user/_search?q=name%3ARichard`

Comment: I was trying to pass them as JSON but it turns out that the second parameter in the gem I was using wasn't for body content but URI encoded the data. Thanks for the help!