# Elasticsearch return all documents of a given type

Tags: search, elasticsearch, types, document, document-types

I have been searching for a solution to this question for a few days. Use case is to simply see the documents of a particular type only. Usually after googling for a long time I end up with some search queries with wildcards. I have gone through many SO Posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874360/elasticsearch-returning-all-documents), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829468/elasticsearch-query-to-return-all-records) and [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-type-query.html) also. I tried below urls but without any luck.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/analytics/test/_search' -d '
{

   "query" : {
   "match_all" : {}
    }
}'

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/analytics/test/_search' -d '
{
    "query": {
        "type":{
            "value": "test"
            }
    }
}'
```

Is there something like a wild card search on a document type to return all documents of that specific doc_type?

Comment: To return all documents - use: `curl localhost:9200/analytics/test/_search`. But what does `doc_type ` mean?

Comment: by default elasticsearch will return only 10 documents... you need to increase the `size` parameter.... though if result is very large itis recommended to use paging query

Comment: @VladimirKovpak doc_type is the document type as in `localhost:9200/<index>/<doc_type>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get all documents from index `analytics` from type `test` just run:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/analytics/test/_search
```

or

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/analytics/test/_search -d '{
    "query": {"match_all" : {}}
}'
```

If you have count of users more than default size value, you need provide `from/size` values like described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html).